# Validate upload file size

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I would like to check the file size, that is if the size exceed, it will prompt the UploadSizeError message. The method is CheckValidate().

```
 var dialogButtons = [
      {
        text: "Upload",
        id: "tpApplicationFormDialog_btnSave",
        disabled: "disabled",
        class: "requiredAtt1",
        click: savetpApplicationFormDialog
      },
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="tpApplicationFormDialog_btnSave" class="requiredAtt1 ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Upload</span></button>
<span class="ui-button-text">Upload</span>
```

**Method**

```
 function CheckValidate() {
        var o = getOptions();
        var f = this.files

        var ret = false;
        if (f.size> 1 || f.fileSize > 1)
        {
            ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
        }
```

**Response**

```
function savetpApplicationFormDialog() {
      if (hasChanges()) {
          commonDialogs.showConfirm(ProjectMessages.ConfirmUpload, function () {
              if(CheckValidate()) {
                  commonDialogs.showProgress(ProjectMessages.UploadSizeError);
              }
                  try {
            commonDialogs.showProgress(ProjectMessages.ProgressUpload);
            var o = getOptions();
            var form = $(o.form);
            form.ajaxSubmit(handleResponse);
          } catch (e) {
            commonDialogs.showError();
          }
        });
      }
    };
```

Comment: how do you trigger this js functions?

Comment: When you click the savetpApplicationFormDialog, it will trigger the savetpApplicationFormDialog function. It will check validate and if file upload exceed size 1, it will trigger ProjectMessage.UploadSizeError.

Comment: `this.files` returns a FileList, you've to pick one of its entries (generally the one at index `0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function CheckValidate() {
        var o = getOptions();
        //var f = this.files
         var f=  $("#idoffileinput").get(0).files[0]['size'] //will give file size in bytes
        var ret = false;
        var maxSize = xxx ;//max size in bytes
        if (f> maxSize )
        {
            ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. The idoffileinput is tpApplicationFormDialog_btnSave, i changed it and it still won't pop up the message. My word file is 65.4kb.

Comment: check the updated answer. check what size is being returned?

Comment: I've encounter this error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: I made some changes and it say "files" is undefined.

Comment: try `($("#idoffileinput"))[0].files[0].size` . also try printing input type file object.

Comment: Hi, the ouput is f = 67030, maxsize = 1, ret = true, but it won't prompt the checkvalidate projectmessage.

Comment: Firstly, check if control is going in `showConfirm` then try using the following code  - `var checkvalidation = CheckValidate() ;if(checkvalidation == true) { commonDialogs.showProgress(ProjectMessages.UploadSizeError);
              }`

Comment: Hi, it seems like it will always go to the try catch method. After making some changes "   else if (CheckValidate() == false) then go to try method. The method works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/lezilu/edit?js,output

JS

```
let input = document.querySelector(".file");
let show = document.querySelector(".show");

input.addEventListener("change", e => {

    let file = e.target.files[0];
    let fileName = file.name;
    let fileSize = file.size;

    if(fileSize < 1000){

        // Less then 1MB

        show.textContent = "Pass";


    }else{

        // Bigger then 1 MB
        show.textContent = "Chose again";

    }



});
```

Comment: Code dumps rarely help. Also, `file.size` is in bytes

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. But i just want the function to check if file is larger than size and then display the projectmessage.uploadsizeerror message.